# after adding google-services.json also i am getting error like

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services. Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.

this is my project gradle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to        all sub-projects/modules.
     apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
     apply plugin: "java"


     buildscript {
     repositories {
    jcenter()
   }
dependencies {

    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-alpha3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha5'

}

}

 allprojects {
 repositories {
      jcenter()
   }
 }
 task clean(type: Delete) {
      delete rootProject.buildDir
 }

   task sourceJar(type: Jar) {
     from sourceSets.main.allJava
     classifier "sources"
   }

  publishing {
       publications {
    mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
        from components.java
        artifact sourceJar
        pom.withXml {
            asNode().appendNode('description', 'A demonstration of Maven  POM customization')
        }
    }
}
    }
```

this is my app.gardle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
 android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
     buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

defaultConfig {

    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    generatedDensities = []
}

aaptOptions {
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
  }

 dependencies {
     compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
      compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.5.jar')
      compile project(':databaseAutoCompleteLibrary')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.2.0'
    compile project(':MPChartLib')
    compile project(':filechooserlibrary')
   compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.2.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
   compile project(':Volley')
   compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
   compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
   compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
   compile 'com.baoyz.swipemenulistview:library:1.3.0'
   compile 'milyn:opencsv:1.6'
   compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
   compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

  }
```

Comment: Have you added the gradle plugin?

Comment: after adding gradle plugin also it is giving error like Error:(4, 0) Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found.

Comment: have you defined the proper jar file and plugin in the app buil.gradle and projec gradle files??

Comment: @user6076314 Refer here http://coderzpassion.com/android-working-latest-google-plus-login-api/    It is explained beautifully step by step with pictures. Hope you will find your error

Comment: i already created key..is there any need to create it again?

Answer (score 2):

Apply this in your app build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
  }
```

In your project build.gradle define

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```